# specify argument has to have keyof property

Tags: typescript

I have the following [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20Coordinate%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Line%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20source%3A%20Coordinate%3B%0D%0A%20%20target%3A%20Coordinate%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20Selector%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%20(d%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20K%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20typeof%20d%5BK%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20LinkVerticalLineProps%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x%3A%20Selector%3CCoordinate%2C%20'x'%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20y%3A%20Selector%3CCoordinate%2C%20'y'%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20implements%20LinkVerticalLineProps%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20originX%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20originY%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(%7B%20x%2C%20y%20%7D%3A%20Coordinate)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.originX%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.originY%20%3D%20y%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x(other%3A%20Coordinate)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20other.x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y(other%3A%20Coordinate)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20other.x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) with the following code:

```
export interface Coordinate {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

export interface Line {
  source: Coordinate;
  target: Coordinate;
}

export type Selector<T, K extends keyof T> = (d: { [key: string]: K }) => typeof d[K];

export interface LinkVerticalLineProps {
  x: Selector<Coordinate, 'x'>;
  y: Selector<Coordinate, 'y'>;
}

class Foo implements LinkVerticalLineProps{
    originX: number;
    originY: number;

    constructor({ x, y }: Coordinate) {
        this.originX = x;
        this.originY = y;
    }

    x(other: Coordinate) {
        return other.x;
    }

    y(other: Coordinate) {
        return other.x;
    }
}
```

But typescript is not happy.

How I can I satisfy the compiler that the `x` function must take an object that has `x` for a property and returns `typeof d[K]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Pick` to pick out just one property of a type :

```
export interface Coordinate {
     x: number;
     y: number;
}

// Use Pick to pick out just one property 
export type Selector<T, K extends keyof T> = (d: Pick<T,K>) => T[K]; // you can also use typeof d[K] but it's the same as T[K] but longer 

//Does the same thing but less repeating the property names 
export type LinkVerticalLineProps = {
    [P in keyof Coordinate]: Selector<Coordinate,P>
}



class Foo implements LinkVerticalLineProps{
    originX: number;
    originY: number;

    constructor({ x, y }: Coordinate) {
        this.originX = x;
        this.originY = y;
    }

    // We must repeat the Pick, ts will not infer class member argument types 
    x(other: Pick<Coordinate, 'x'>) {
        return other.x;
    }

    y(other: Pick<Coordinate, 'y'>) {
        return other.y;
    }
}
```